# Creditor badge possible bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, badges

The badge description states:

> First citation of a topic or example you haven't contributed to, in an answer you posted.

Although the [Creditor badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5851/creditor) script has run several times today, I can't determine why I haven't been awarded the badge.

**Attempts 1 and 2:**

Yesterday, I initially tried adding [a documentation link to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494974/how-to-add-a-segue-programmatically/34495715#34495715) of mine.

- When it didn't work, I replaced the unversioned link with the versioned one obtained via that topic's share button. That still didn't seem to make a difference.

*Although I had never contributed to that **Using Segues** topic, I had contributed to other topics for the iOS tag documentation.*

*Thinking that might be the reason, I chose a different (Objective-C) documentation tag  which I hadn't contributed to at all.*

**Attempts 3 and 4:**

I tried [adding a different documentation link to a topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431977/extension-property-crashes-in-nsstring-category/30432905#30432905) in different post of mine.

- Again, that didn't seem to count, even though I tried a link to a) the topic, and b) a specific example.

**What's going on?**

The link doesn't have to be from a new answer, as [some of the 12 other people that have earned the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5851/creditor) accomplished it by editing doc links into older answers.

Each time, I waited for the badge script to run before trying something different, so none of the four documentation links seemed to count.

*Interestingly, I helped someone else [earn the badge when I edited a documentation link into their question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589181/set-operations-union-intersection-on-swift-array/29852086#29852086).*

Either there's some subtle bug at work, or I'm overlooking some reason why my own posts haven't met the criteria for that badge.

**Update:**

[animuson tried editing the documentation link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30432905/revisions) and I still didn't get credit, although someone else got a badge since then, bringing the total up to 13.

That seems like a low number. Perhaps there's some other undocumented criteria for the badge?

Once SEDE is updated, it will be interesting to see how many users actually have posts containing doc links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post needs to be **upvoted** after the Docs link is added for the badge to be awarded.

These posts from Docs private beta may help:

- http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/badges-description-for-bluebook-creditor-and-knowledgeable?noredirect=1
- http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1207/unable-to-get-creditor-badge?noredirect=1

Comment: I looked at all the posts listed for the badge, and each one had been upvoted after the documentation link was added! Thanks for sharing this undocumented badge requirement.

Comment: @PetahChristian I've upvoted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494974/how-to-add-a-segue-programmatically/34495715#34495715, you should be able to get the badge :)

Comment: [That triggered the badge being awarded](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5851/creditor?userid=4151918), although I hope the upvote was solely based on the answer's merit.  Otherwise, please feel free to reverse your vote, as I didn't desire to unfairly earn the badge.

Comment: @PetahChristian Yup, it's a good and clear answer :)