# Revise description for Creditor badge to include its additional requirement

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, badges

Documentation's [Creditor badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5851/creditor) description states:

> First citation of a topic or example you haven't contributed to, in an answer you posted.

However, the badge has an additional requirement, since the answer containing the citation [must receive an upvote *after* the citation is added](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329086/creditor-badge-possible-bug).

The badge description should be clarified to include this additional requirement:

> First citation of a topic or example you haven't contributed to, in an answer you posted, and the answer receives an upvote.

*This is a bit wordier than "in an upvoted answer you posted," but it eliminates any confusion from not earning the badge by merely editing a citation into an existing answer that already has upvotes.*

Comment: "First upvoted citation..." might be a good way to condense all requirements into one fairly readable sentence.